# Is SAT-Problem with XOR and AND NP-complete

Tags: np-complete, satisfiability, 2-sat

Is this problem NP-complete?

I have many restrictions like this and want to find a feasible solution:

((a and b) xor (c and d)) = 1

with a,b,c,d are arbitrary literals. It looks similar to XOR-2SAT but has additional ANDs inside the clause.

Comment: Are the ANDs mostly of 2 literals? ​ ​

Comment: yes they are!!!

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  Can you be more precise?  Do *all* and-clauses have exactly 2 literals?  are literals always in positive form, or could they be negated?  Are the xor's always of exactly 2 and-clauses?  Can you edit the question accordingly?

Answer (score 4):

Your question is likely answered by [Schaefer's dichotomy theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schaefer%27s_dichotomy_theorem). In particular, if an instance of your problem is a conjunction of formulas, each one depending on a bounded number of variables, then according to the theorem your problem is either in P or NP-complete; and moreover there is a simple criterion to decide which case it is.