# Is ANF-SAT P or NP?

Tags: complexity-theory, satisfiability, p-vs-np

Given a finite set of equations in [ANF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_normal_form), for example:
$$
\begin{cases}
(x_1 \land x_2) \oplus (x_1 \land x_3 \land x_4) \oplus 1 = 0  \\
x_3 \oplus (x_2 \land x_3 \land x_4) = 0 \\
(x_1 \land x_4) \oplus (x_1 \land x_2) \oplus (x_3 \land x_4) = 0
\end{cases}
$$

Is this P or NP?

The only assumption is that number of variables is finite.

I know it can be converted to CNF and become NP-Complete, but I can't find an algorithm for converting a general ANF to CNF which is P (so this does not imply it is NP-Complete)

This is also different from [XOR-SAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem#XOR-satisfiability) as it is not linear and so Gaussian elimination is not an option.

The answer might be using [Schaefer's dichotomy theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schaefer%27s_dichotomy_theorem), but I'm not sure if it applies or not.

This is similar to [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/63644/is-sat-problem-with-xor-and-and-np-complete) but the OP was not clear about question and there is also no clear answer, so I'm asking a clear one here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking about the problem where the input is a system of equations in ANF (algebraic normal form) and the output is whether the system of equations is satisfiable, this problem is NP-complete.

There is a reduction from 3SAT.  Suppose we have a 3CNF formula $\varphi = C_1 \land \cdots \land C_m$, where $C_i$ is the $i$th clause in $\varphi$, with variables $x_1,\dots,x_n$.  We'll create a system of ANF equations that are satisfiable iff $\varphi$ is satisfiable, as follows.

First, let's take care of any negations in $\varphi$.  For each variable $x_i$, introduce another variable $y_i$, along with the ANF equation

$$1 \oplus x_i \oplus y_i = 0.$$

Then, we can replace each negated literal $\neg x_j$ in $\varphi$ with $y_j$.  In this way we obtain a 3CNF formula with only non-negated literals.

Next, we will introduce one ANF equation per clause, as follows.  Introduce variables $z_1,\dots,z_m$.  Suppose clause $C_i$ has the form $a \lor b \lor c$ (after removing negations).  Then we will generate the ANF equation

$$z_i + abc + ab + bc + ac + a + b + c = 0.$$

Notice that this forces $z_i$ to be true iff clause $C_i$ is satisfied.

Finally, add the ANF equation

$$1 + z_1 z_2 \cdots z_m = 0.$$

This forces all of the $z_i$ to be true, i.e., all of the clauses $C_i$ to be satisfied.

Now the system of all ANF equations generated in this way is satisfiable, iff $\varphi$ is satisfiable.